# How to get (scrape) the contents of a site that requires logging in through YQL?

Tags: yql, yahoo-api

Is it possible to get (scrape) data from a site that requires logging in using YQL? If yes, please tell the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the user to authorize your access via OAuth, as [YQL's docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/authorization.html) mention.  In addition to the docs pointed to by links from the URL I just mentioned, you can learn all about OAuth [here](http://oauth.net/), then get libraries to help you use OAuth, depending of course on the programming language you want to use, from the links listed [here](http://oauth.net/code/).

Comment: what about the cookies?? where are the cookies going to be saved??

Comment: You need OAuth to _sign_ YQL requests, no cookies needed -- see e.g. the all-Javascript example at http://kentbrewster.com/oauth-baby-steps/ , if you're comfortable with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the remote site is set up, you could use a simple POST (there is an open data table for that<sup>1</sup>) or you could create your own small, custom data table and use `<execute>`<sup>2</sup> to send whatever headers (including `Cookie:`) you need over one or more GET/POST requests.

1. [htmlpost data table](http://github.com/yql/yql-tables/blob/master/data/htmlpost.xml) ([example](http://tinyurl.com/yql-htmlpost-example))
2. [YQL Execute](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-execute-chapter.html)